git lost a commit after stash and merge
I had a weird problem yesterday.

committed change on branch add-trans with log message add transaction final
checked out to branch react, but one file was modified, I had to stash it
stashed the file
checked out master (by mistake)
checked out react
merged branch add-trans
dropped stash. actually don't need it.

Everything good so far
But then realize the commit "add transaction final" was missing !
git log --graph --oneline --decorate

*   ea34d09 (react) Merge branch 'add-trans' into react
|\  
* | 0a5cd5a dark theme
* | 49b3148 added color categorie
* | 5aaf600 ordering categories
| * 60d0bc5 (HEAD -> add-trans) add new transaction. draft 1
* | aef34ed merge categories and groups selection
|/  
| * 6ddb28d (master) moved flatpickr cdn
| * 6c3954f (origin/master, origin/HEAD) show amount if 0
...

Damned ! lost 4 hours of work.
What happened ?!
I know git does not erase stuff easilly, so I could find the lost hash based on the post : How do I recover a dropped stash in Git?
git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all $( git fsck --no-reflog | awk '/dangling commit/ {print $3}' )

*   ea34d09 (react) Merge branch 'add-trans' into react
|\  
* | 0a5cd5a dark theme
* | 49b3148 added color categorie
* | 5aaf600 ordering categories
| | *   5c96e57 WIP on (no branch): faa2f21 add transaction final
| | |\  
| | | * 558aef4 index on (no branch): faa2f21 add transaction final
| | |/  
| | * faa2f21 add transaction final
| |/  
| * 60d0bc5 (HEAD -> add-trans) add new transaction. draft 1
* | aef34ed merge categories and groups selection
|/  
| * 6ddb28d (master) moved flatpickr cdn
| * 6c3954f (origin/master, origin/HEAD) show amount if 0
...

I could get back the commit faa2f21 add transaction final and merge correctly, but I'm confused... can anyone tell me what happened ?
git reflog (after I fixed the problem)

0522a6d (HEAD -> react) HEAD@{0}: commit (merge): Merge branch 'add-trans' into react
0a5cd5a HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from add-trans to react
faa2f21 (add-trans) HEAD@{2}: merge add-trans-final: Fast-forward
60d0bc5 HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from react to add-trans
0a5cd5a HEAD@{4}: reset: moving to HEAD~1
ea34d09 HEAD@{5}: checkout: moving from add-trans to react
60d0bc5 HEAD@{6}: checkout: moving from faa2f21c33ce8da763e8d5580c718590318ed5c1 to add-trans
faa2f21 (add-trans) HEAD@{7}: checkout: moving from add-trans to faa2f21
60d0bc5 HEAD@{8}: checkout: moving from react to add-trans
ea34d09 HEAD@{9}: commit (merge): Merge branch 'add-trans' into react
0a5cd5a HEAD@{10}: checkout: moving from master to react
6ddb28d (master) HEAD@{11}: checkout: moving from faa2f21c33ce8da763e8d5580c718590318ed5c1 to master
faa2f21 (add-trans) HEAD@{12}: commit: add transaction final
60d0bc5 HEAD@{13}: checkout: moving from react to 60d0bc5a707cf626b416a66cad6df75dc167a18c
0a5cd5a HEAD@{14}: commit: dark theme
49b3148 HEAD@{15}: commit: added color categorie
...

Thanks a lot.

It looks like your first bullet point might be incorrect. It looks like commit ID faa2f21 was not created while add-trans was checked out, because that commit is just sitting there with no branch pointing to it. OR, maybe it was at the time, but perhaps you did a reset or rebase which changed branch add-trans to point back one commit to 60d0bc5 instead. You could try git reflog and find when commit faa2f21 was created- that might give you more context before and after that.

Thanks. Added the reflog infos.  I now see that after commit faa2f21 I moved to shortly to master

I think my hunch in the previous comment was right. Based on the edit with the reflog entries, it looks like at the time you created commit faa2f21 you weren't on a branch, but sometime after the reflog entries you showed, you did repoint add-trans to commit ID faa2f21, which is where it's pointing now. So, 1.) does it seem possible that you checked out 60d0bc5 instead of add-trans, and 2.) Do you remember re-pointing add-trans to faa2f21 after you realized it wasn't on the branch? (Perhaps the more recent reflog entries you didn't show might show that.)

When you merged, did you merge the local branch (git merge add-trans) or did you merge the remote branch (git merge origin/add-trans)?

Side note: I can't quite figure out what this reflog entry is: 0a5cd5a. It seems like it would make more sense if that was 49b3148 since that's what react was pointing to 3 entries down when you moved off of it.

@amphetamachine I think reflog entries would display origin/add-trans if that were the case. I also just checked what happens if you checkout origin/add-trans instead of add-trans, and the reflog entry lists origin/add-trans as well, so my guess is OP actually checked out the commit ID instead of the branch somehow.

@amphetamachine add-trans is a local branch, merged locally.

@TTT  1) it seems to be the reason why the merge was done on 60d0bc5. I checked out to add-transusing the VSCode GUI, so I'm not really sure. git reflog  shows a clear move to 60d0bc5 HEAD@{13}: checkout: moving from react to 60d0bc5, though. 2) No, I never realized the branch was not pointing on faa2f21. The more recent reflog are only showing how I fixed the whole story afterwards.

@TTT answering your side note., I added more history to the log. 0a5cd5awas missing in my copy-paste.

@gis I'm guessing 0a5cd5a is missing from the reflog too? That commit should have been created after 49b3148 and it seems to appear out of nowhere.

@TTT yes, sorry... I tried to minimize message size. Re-edited the reflog now

@gis OK. Now the reflog is consistent with the generated graph. I can also see that the graphs are before you made the fix, and the reflog is after the fix. There's now enough info to accurately answer, which I just did.

The problem is that your first bullet point didn't happen as you thought it did:

committed change on branch add-trans with log message add transaction final

Instead, this line of the reflog explains exactly what happened:
60d0bc5 HEAD@{13}: checkout: moving from react to 60d0bc5a707cf626b416a66cad6df75dc167a18c

Note at the time that checkout occurred, branch add-trans was pointing to commit ID 60d0bc5. If you had checked out branch add-trans, the reflog would have said:
60d0bc5 HEAD@{13}: checkout: moving from react to add-trans

and had you done that the issue wouldn't have occurred. But by checking out the commit ID instead of the branch, you ended up in detached mode, and then when you created commit faa2f21 add transaction final it became an orphaned commit, which you later found by searching for the stash that was created while your detached HEAD was pointing to that commit.
As for how it happened, in a comment you stated you thought you did this:

I checked out to add-trans using the VSCode GUI, so I'm not really sure.

Depending on which VS Code plugin you were using the exact details may differ, but in Git Graph for example, if you right click on a branch name and select "Checkout branch" it will do so, but if you right click on the commit message (just slightly to the right of the branch name), and right click and select "Checkout" it will checkout as detached. (It will also warn you of this which you can dismiss, or dismiss forever meaning the next time it won't warn you.) I'm guessing you accidentally did something similar to this and didn't realize it until after the merge.
The fix is relatively straight forward, once you know the orphaned commit ID, which is typically easy to find by using git reflog. I can tell from your reflog entries that you did fix it.

Ok thanks a lot for your clear analysis. I will try to reproduce this weird checkout.

hum... Still don't understand why the drop stash did remove the faa2f21 

@gis dropping the stash didn't remove that commit. It's still there, but since it's orphaned you don't have anything pointing to it, so it doesn't show up in a normal git log. That's why in the last paragraph I suggest using git reflog when this sort of thing happens so you can easily find the "hidden" commit ID. The same sort of thing happens to rewritten commits after a rebase: new commits are created and the old commit IDs become orphaned, but you can still find them with git reflog.

All clear, thanks. thx to you, I'm now at ease with reflog.

What you described with GitGraph is exactly what might have happened. Though I do not remember having the warning poping up, I could reproduce the "right click on commit message" scenario.

The WIP on (no branch) in your log output indicates you were in the middle of a rebase or conflict resolution, or perhaps even a merge --no-commit.
Git will let you add/amend commits but until you resolve the repository state, merging add-trans will use the last known good state of the branch.
Really, I don't know what's going on with the state of your local repository. git status is your friend and can tell you much about what's going on in your repository.
Here are some commands to try:
git rebase --abort
git am --abort
git merge --abort
git bisect reset

Once you get it back, then you can pull that weird thing you committed into the void into your branch:
git checkout add-trans
git cherry-pick faa2f21

Then re-merge into react.
Better Git Prompt
If you can't be arsed to type git status every time, you can add repo state indicators into your prompt using git-prompt.sh:
# Add these lines to ~/.bashrc:
. /usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-prompt
PS1='[\u@\h \W$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")]\$ '

You should adjust the git-sh-prompt line to where it resides on your system. I just included the path that's the default in Ubuntu 23.04.

Actually that "WIP on" message is auto-generated by the stash.
